# issue with using inject to convert array to hash

Tags: ruby

```
data_arr = [['dog', 'Fido'], ['cat', 'Whiskers'], ['fish', 'Fluffy']]

data_hash = data_arr.inject({}) do |hsh, v|
    hsh[v[0]] = v[1]
    hsh
end
```

Hi, why do I not need to initialize data_hash as an empty hash? And why do I have to add hsh in the last line if not it will result in an error.

Comment: Do you know what is it that `inject` does? And how it uses its block? Reading the documentation might help.

Comment: So, if your question is about using inject to do this, go read inject's documentation and maybe come back with a better question. if you don't care about inject and only need the hash, then use `data_arr.to_h` or `Hash[data_arr]` (if the first one doesn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why do I not need to initialize `data_hash` as an empty hash?

You do, implicitly. The value passed to `inject`, i.e. `{}` will become the initial value for `hsh` which will eventually become the value for `data_hash`. According to the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

> At the end of the iteration, the final value of *memo* is the return value for the method.

Let's see what happens if we don't pass `{}`:

> If you do not explicitly specify an *initial* value for *memo*, then the first element of collection is used as the initial value of *memo*.

The first element of your collection is the array `['dog', 'Fido']`. If you omit `{}`, then `inject` would use that array as the initial value for `hsh`. The subsequent call to `hsh[v[0]] = v[1]` would fail, because of:

```
hsh = ['dog', 'Fido']
hsh['cat'] = 'Whiskers'
#=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

> why do I have to add hsh in the last line

Again, let's check the documentation:

> [...] the result [of the specified block] becomes the new value for *memo*.

`inject` expects you to return the new value for `hsh` at the end of the block.

> if not it will result in an error.

That's because an assignment like `hsh[v[0]] = v[1]` returns the assigned value, e.g. `'Fido'`. So if you omit the last line, `'Fido'` becomes the new value for `hsh`:

```
hsh = 'Fido'
hsh['cat'] = 'Whiskers'
#=> IndexError: string not matched
```

---

There's also [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) which works similar to `inject`, but assumes that you want to mutate the same object within the block. It therefore doesn't require you to return it at the end of the block: (note that the argument order is reversed)

```
data_hash = data_arr.each_with_object({}) do |v, hsh|
  hsh[v[0]] = v[1]
end
#=> {"dog"=>"Fido", "cat"=>"Whiskers", "fish"=>"Fluffy"}
```

or using [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition):

```
data_hash = data_arr.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), hsh|
  hsh[k] = v
end
#=> {"dog"=>"Fido", "cat"=>"Whiskers", "fish"=>"Fluffy"}
```

Although to convert your array to a hash you can simply use [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h), which is

> [...] interpreting *ary* as an array of `[key, value]` pairs

```
data_arr.to_h
#=> {"dog"=>"Fido", "cat"=>"Whiskers", "fish"=>"Fluffy"}
```

Comment: Note that the question is "why do I __not__ need to initialize...". Is that "not" not supposed to be there? Or are they asking "why don't I have to do `data_hash = {}` before the inject?" Who knows! :shrug:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks, totally overlooked that :-) I've updated my answer.